# React/Jest error: Imported function not recognized

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am trying to setup Jest for testing in my React app. It works fine on some basic functions, but when I try to import a function from a node module and use it, it throws a Type error: `TypeError: (0 , _reactCssThemr.themr) is not a function`

To try to narrow down the issue, I've stripped out most of the config and am just testing a dummy component, but still get the error. I can't seem to figure out what I have wrong here, I assume it's related to the config. It seems like it's just not getting the node module.

Basic test:

```
import JestTest from 'components/JestTest.jsx';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('CompsCards', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    const e = TestRenderer.create(<JestTest />).toJSON();
    expect(e).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

JestText.jsx:

```
import theme from 'css-modules/JestTest.css';
import { themr } from 'react-css-themr';

export class JestTest extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const {theme} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={theme.JestTest}>Why no workey?</div>
    );
  }
}

const ThemedJestTest = themr('JestTest', theme)(JestTest);

export default ThemedJestTest;
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  verbose: true,
  setupFiles: ['./jest-setup.js'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'css'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^components/(.+)$': '<rootDir>/src/client/components/$1',
    '^css-modules/(.+)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',

    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
   }
 };
```

jest-setup.jsx

```
require.requireActual('babel-polyfill');
```

Comment: Try removing the curly braces surrounding themr

Comment: @ZachL - Doing so gets me `TypeError: (0 , _reactCssThemr2.default) is not a function` - but regardless even if it had worked, this wouldn't be a viable long-term solution since the `themr` function isn't the default export of that package.